# How to simplify Into()

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

I have this code, where `XYBin` is a superset of `Bin`:

```
impl Into<Bin> for XYBin {
    fn into(self) -> Bin {
         Bin {
            packets_tx: self.packets_tx, 
            octets_tx: self.octets_tx, 
            packets_rx: self.packets_tx, 
            octets_rx: self.octets_rx, 
            packets_rx_on_only: self.packets_rx_on_only, 
            octets_rx_on_only: self.octets_rx_on_only, 
            packets_rx_on: self.packets_rx_on, 
            octets_rx_on: self.octets_rx_on
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way of using punning, or another approach (except macros) to reduce the repetitive code?

Comment: If the essence of your logic depends on `Bin` then  explicitly declaring it as subset might be more advantageous for your case : `XYBin{ base: Bin, extensions: ... }` then simply return the `base`

Comment: @ÖmerErden Generally that would be a good idea, but `XYBin` is a row type used with SQLx, and so needs to be flat.

Comment: Note: I've found an accidental typo in one of my field names.  This sort of bug is a good reason for removing this sort of code.

Comment: @fadedbee [Use the `flatten` attribute](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/trait.FromRow.html#flatten)

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo That's exactly what I needed, but wasn't looking for.  If you turn this into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

What I had before was:

```
#[derive(sqlx::FromRow, Debug)]
struct XYBin { 
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
    packets_tx: i64,
    octets_tx: i64,
    packets_rx: i64,
    octets_rx: i64,
    packets_rx_on_only: Vec<i64>,
    octets_rx_on_only: Vec<i64>,
    packets_rx_on: Vec<i64>,
    octets_rx_on: Vec<i64>
}
 
impl Into<Bin> for XYBin {
    fn into(self) -> Bin {
         Bin {
            packets_tx: self.packets_tx, 
            octets_tx: self.octets_tx, 
            packets_rx: self.packets_rx, 
            octets_rx: self.octets_rx, 
            packets_rx_on_only: self.packets_rx_on_only, 
            octets_rx_on_only: self.octets_rx_on_only, 
            packets_rx_on: self.packets_rx_on, 
            octets_rx_on: self.octets_rx_on
       }
    }
}
 
#[derive(Debug, Serialize)]
struct Bin {
    packets_tx: i64,
    octets_tx: i64,
    packets_rx: i64,
    octets_rx: i64,
    packets_rx_on_only: Vec<i64>,
    octets_rx_on_only: Vec<i64>,
    packets_rx_on: Vec<i64>,
    octets_rx_on: Vec<i64>
}
```

After reading ColonelThirtyTwo's comment, I now have:

```
#[derive(sqlx::FromRow, Debug)]
struct XYBin { 
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
    #[sqlx(flatten)]
    bin: Bin
}
 
impl Into<Bin> for XYBin {
    fn into(self) -> Bin {
        self.bin
    }
}
 
#[derive(sqlx::FromRow, Debug, Serialize)]
struct Bin {
    packets_tx: i64,
    octets_tx: i64,
    packets_rx: i64,
    octets_rx: i64,
    packets_rx_on_only: Vec<i64>,
    octets_rx_on_only: Vec<i64>,
    packets_rx_on: Vec<i64>,
    octets_rx_on: Vec<i64>
}
```

Comment: Note that it's better to implement `From` than `Into`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Thanks, I found the source/reason: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html "One should always prefer implementing From over Into because implementing From automatically provides one with an implementation of Into thanks to the blanket implementation in the standard library."